# Simple password authentication in TCP client server architecture

Tags: tcp, client-server, password-protection, password-encryption

Good morning everyone.
I've been reading (most of it here in stack overflow) about how to make a secure password authentication (hashing n times, using salt, etc) but I'm in doubt of how I'll actually implement it in my TCP client-server architecture.

I have already implemented and tested the methods I need (using jasypt digester), but my doubt is where to do the hashing and its verification.

As for what I read, a good practice is to avoid transmitting the password. In this case, the server would send the hashed password and the client would test it with the one entered by the user. After that I have to tell the server if the authentication was successful or not. Ok, this won't work becouse anyone who connect to the socket the server is reading and send a "authentication ok" will be logged on.

The other option is to send the password's has to the server. In this case I don't see any actual benefit from hashing, since the "attacker" will have to just send the same hash to authenticate.

Probably I'm not getting some details, so, can anyone give me a light on this?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is *definitely on the side that permanently stores the hashes of the passwords*.

The long answer: hashing passwords only allows to prevent an attacker with read-only access to your passwords storage (e.g. database) from escalating to higher power levels and to prevent you knowing the actual secret password, because lots of users use same pass across multiple services (good description [here](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/) and [here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)). That is why you need to do the validation on the storage side (because otherwize, as you've mentioned, attacker would just send "validation ok" message and that's it).

However if you want to implement truly secure connection, simple passwords hashing is not enough (as you've also mentioned, attacker could sniff TCP traffic and reveal the hash). For this purpose you need to establish a secure connection, which is much harder than just hashing password (in web world a page where you enter your pass should always be served over HTTPS). The SSL/TLS should be used for this, however these protocols lie on top of TCP, so you might need another solution (in common, you need to have a trusted certificate source, need to validate the server cert, need to generate a common symmetric encryption key and then encrypt all data you send). After you've established secure encrypted connection, encrypted data is useless to sniff, the attacker would never know the hash of the password.